# How to minimize unwanted net usage by processes to a trickle?

Tags: networking, internet, operating-systems, bandwidth, windows-networking

I have this problem sometimes of what seems like excessive Internet bandwidth usage. Sometimes I have to use a metered connection, so the issue becomes more important. Leaving aside things like malware (which may happen, and for which I do have anti-malware software installed), what are some ways to reduce Internet usage (other than that directly initiated by the user) to a trickle, so as not to waste bandwidth and money? Thanks in advance for all answers.

I'll mention one way that I am exploring: NetBalancer for Windows. A friend also told me about nethogs for Linux. Not tried yet, but will.

Comment: What problems/symptoms have you observed that made you think you have excessive Internet bandwidth usage? Maybe you should ask about that. For example, if you have a router that doesn't do Smart Queueing ([CoDel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoDel) or [PIE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-aqm-pie-08), plus [ECN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification)), you may have a [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) problem. In that case, throttling background traffic isn't the best solution; the best solution is to deploy Smart Queueing.

Comment: @Spiff: No router. 3G USB modem. Symptoms: Earlier when doing light usage, say a few static web pages and Gmail (standard (JS) view) in browser tabs, download speed shown in dialer used to be 10s to 100s of Kbps - ok. Recently for the same usage it is 2 to 8 Mbps - not ok, since metered connection. Disabled Google Drive  client, better a bit, but problem still there.

Comment: @Spiff: Also had done these steps earlier: Started Windows Task Manager, added the I/O (reads/writes) columns to the output, viewed it for some time, saw Google Drive using net a lot, disabled it, things improved some, problem came again later, likewise saw Dropbox client using net a lot, disabled it. Situation intermittently better after those steps. First of all, had uninstalled many net-using apps that were not being used, w/ Revo Uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

## A. Use a firewall (external to windows) to control traffic.

- This is what a firewall is for, you can have a better firewall than the one in Windows (iptables/firewalld or pf) for almost nothing.
- This solution can protect/manage traffic on the boundary of your entire network (including your mobile phone perhaps?), or you could split it into a few zones with different settings.  The point is blocking traffic leaving your network , not leaving your computer, though you can do both.
- You can set it up and save it.  Next time you need to re-install your computer or change hardware, you still have a firewall. It is a set-backup-forget kind of thing.
- You can also add up-to-date public blacklists such as [shallalist.de](http://www.shallalist.de/categories.html)  ( Click "Download" next to "md5")
- You can find these features in routers and certain switches also.

[Build a *nix firewall for very cheap](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/1lfkvm/miniature_linux_firewall_with_builtin_screen/)

[Example Linux firewall setup](http://www.tecmint.com/manage-and-limit-downloadupload-bandwidth-with-trickle-in-linux/)

[Example consumer firewall](http://www.firewalls.com/videos/sonicwall/bandwidth-management-series.html)